# How to open file as formatted string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file

I have a series of files with lots of variables defined in the form `{myvar}` inside. e.g.

file.txt

```
This is {myvar}.
```

I want to open them, and have the variables being replaced normally:

```
with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r') as file:
    myfile = file.read().replace('\n', '')


myvar='myself.'
print(f"{myfile}")
```

Should output:

```
This is myself.
```

How can I open the file as a formatted string? Or convert the string to *formatted* string?

Comment: You can do something like `file.read().format(myvar='myself')`, or if you prefer to have all the replacements in a dict like `replacements = {'myvar': 'myself'}` and then `file.read().format(**replacements)`. If you want to use variable names, then `file.read().format(**locals())` or `file.read().format(**globals())`.

Comment: Also, look into Jinja2: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/ . It's a *very* nice template language

Comment: @jdehesa could you please explain further how the `.format(**locals())` or `**globals()` would work? I would still need to use a dictionary such as `replacements` that you showed right?

Comment: @Ben it looks great, wasn't aware of it! If you have an example it would be great

Comment: @Sosi No, [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) return a dictionary themselves, so [unpacking them with `**`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) will directly make them work as keyword-based replacements.

Comment: @Sosi I'm gonna star this and try to come back with a good answer this evening if someone hasn't made one by then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work if the variable is local to the call, if it's a global variable, use `**globals()`. You can also put the value in a dictionary that has the variable name as the key.

```
myvar = 'myself'
newline = '\n'  # Avoids SyntaxError: f-string expr cannot include a backslash

with open('unformatted.txt', 'r') as file:
    myfile = f"{file.read().replace(newline, '')}".format(**locals())

print(myfile)
```

Comment: Before seeing this answer, I spent 30 mins trying to understand why a working example was fine (such as the one you give), but when I had it in a function it wasn't working. Now I see why :)

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there.

Assume there is "This is {myvar}." in file.txt.

Coding:

```
with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r') as file:
    myfile = file.read().replace('\n', '')

myvar='myself'

print(myfile.format(myvar=myvar))
```

Any strings in plain text format, can be imported as a variable from a text file. Then the strings variable can be manipulated as normal.

In you case, the key is "{var}". So you can easily use ".format(var=varx) as long as you defined variable "varx".

Output:

> This is myself.

And if you want to import html template with css style and replace some contents, you can just use "{{" and "}}" to escape "{" and "}".

Example 2
In file:

> This is {myvar} for a {{var}}.

Output:

> This is myself for a {var}.